# Expression issue for derived column in ssis package

Tags: ssis

I have an string like this format. In my case I need to extract only the characters from string

case

```
1)12AB
2)SD12
3)1WE4
```

output

```
1)AB
2)SD
3)WE
```

I need to extract only the characters. I am using this expression in the derived column in SSIS package

```
SUBSTRING(MediaIDCode,1,2)
```

but this expression works for only this condition

```
1)12AB
```

I need to get an expression that works for all the conditions above

Answer (score 0):

Use a script component and RegEx to remove numeric values

```
Row.description = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Row.description, "[^0-9]", "");
```